# Make React AppBar and SplitPane fit without scrollbar

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am making a React page that has an AppBar up top and then a SplitPane below it so that the user can edit and preview content and also adjust the sizing. The problem is the SplitPane seems to be sizing itself as if the AppBar were not present, which messes up the UI quite a lot: both panes in the SplitPane are scrollable, and then the root view is scrollable as well. I want only the panes to be scrollable.

I have tried this with both react-split-pane and react-splitter-layout, and I run into this issue with both. (I actually like react-splitter-layout better because it looks good out of the box, but I see react-split-pane is much more widely-used. I suspect a fix for one would work for the other as well.)

I have tried using CSS to set the height of the SplitPane and its parent to `calc(100% - ${appBarHeight}px)` (based on how Material UI does the Drawer), but it has not worked. I've tried wrapping it in divs with various CSS (setting height, flex, display) and in Material UI's Box, but nothing has worked so far.

I was able to hack a solution by putting the AppBar into one of the panes, but this is clearly a poor choice as the pane is just one of many screens and I don't want to duplicate it everywhere.

This is a simple example which exhibits the problem I am having:

```
import React from 'react';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import SplitPane from 'react-split-pane';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AppBar position="static" color="default">
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit">
            Photos
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <SplitPane>
         <div>A</div>
         <div>B</div>
      </SplitPane>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

So what I expected from the above is to end up with a page with the header saying "Photos", a vertical pane with "A", a vertical pane with "B", and no scrollbars since the content is very short. Instead, a scrollbar shows up for the whole page and you can scroll down the height of the AppBar. How can I address this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the SplitPane inside your AppBar inside an element with "relative" position. This is described in the [maxSize section of the documentation](https://github.com/tomkp/react-split-pane#maxsize) of react-split-pane.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AppBar position="static" color="default">
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit">
            Photos
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
        <main style={{ position: "relative" }}>
         <SplitPane>
           <div style={{ padding: "0 2rem" }}>
             A
           </div>
           <div style={{ padding: "0 2rem" }}>
             B
           </div>
         </SplitPane>
        </main>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I don't have time to test this in the short term, but next time I need this in a project I'll try it out

Comment: I just tried this now and it did not work. I'll admit that I did not understand the section of the documentation that you linked to. I know my way is wrong, but it's for a personal project and the hack works, so I'm not going to waste time figuring out why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to figure out a hack to make this work, and thought I should share for the next person to run into this issue.

Basically the idea is to make a split at the boundary of the AppBar with an immovable pane. This is working in my larger project. Below is an untested demonstration of the general idea:

```
import React from 'react';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import SplitPane from 'react-split-pane';

const appBarHeight = 65;

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SplitPane split="horizontal" minSize={appBarHeight} maxSize={appBarHeight}>
         <div></div>
         <div>
           <SplitPane>
             <div>A</div>
             <div>B</div>
           </SplitPane>
         </div>
      </SplitPane>
      <div style={{ position: 'absolute', width: "100%" }}>
        <AppBar position="static" style={{ height: appBarHeight }}>
          <Toolbar>
            <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit">
              Photos
            </Typography>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```